# How do I inject packets to a tap interface?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualization

I'm trying to find a way to use a tap interface to test some networking capture code.  We are passively capturing wifi data and processing it through some analysis software.  I would like to build some automated testing around these apps and so would like to control the data that the wifi device provides.  I thought of using a tap device to simulate the wifi card.  But I'm not sure how to inject my simulated traffic into it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this article that explains it very clearly.
[tuntap tutorial](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/)

Comment: While the link may explain in detail, link-answers are generally discouraged. By also posting the relevant information from that link here, you help protect against link rot, as well as esuring that superuser is the final stop for a sollution, rather than an index.